# How can I get the mime-type of an Image class instance in memory in c#?

Tags: c#, image, mime-types

In a library I am writing for some infrastructure projects at work, I have a method to create various scales of an image (for thumbnails etc...).  However, the system that I am storing this data in is requiring a mime-type declared in the database for various reasons.

Is there a way to get a Mime type from the passed in c# `Image` class, or will I have to have external applications pass in the Mimetype along with the image?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can get the [`ImageFormat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.imageformat.aspx) from the `Image`, and you can get the MIME type from the [`ImageCodecInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.imagecodecinfo.aspx). All you need to do is tie the two together:

```
ImageFormat format = yourImage.RawFormat;
ImageCodecInfo codec = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageDecoders().First(c => c.FormatID == format.Guid);
string mimeType = codec.MimeType;
```

Comment: When I use this code in my .NET 6 project I receive a [CA1416](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca1416) warning `This call site is reachable on all platforms. 'ImageCodecInfo.MimeType' is only supported on: 'windows'.`  
I don't suppose there is a cross-platform way of doing this? I am looking for a solution that can be used in Blazor wasm.

Comment: @LukeTO'Brien Not with the `System.Drawing.Common` library - that's only supported on Windows. [Breaking change: System.Drawing.Common only supported on Windows - .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/core-libraries/6.0/system-drawing-common-windows-only)

Comment: @LukeTO'Brien Microsoft seem to be recommending [SkiaSharp](https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp/) as a cross-platform replacement.